# gen:custom-write for Racket classes

Tags: racket

I am looking for the canonical way to specify custom methods to output the fields of a Racket object. In other words I'm looking for the Racket equivalent of Java's `toString` method (if it exists).

I know that for structs one can use `gen:custom-write` to specify the `write-proc` function ([source](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html)). Is there something similar for classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for `custom-write`. Since [`gen:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._gen~3acustom-write%29%29) is a wrapper around [`prop:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._prop~3acustom-write%29%29), it is possible to have a class implement it through an interface.

The [`printable<%>`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objectprinting.html) interface implements [`prop:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._prop~3acustom-write%29%29) to allow things like this:

```
#lang racket

(define fish%
  (class* object% (printable<%>)
    (super-new)
    (define/public (custom-print out depth)
      (fprintf out "><,`>"))
    (define/public (custom-write out)
      (fprintf out "><,`>"))
    (define/public (custom-display out)
      (fprintf out "><,`>"))))
```

Using it:

```
> (new fish%)
><,`>
```

This is possible because the [`printable<%>`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objectprinting.html) interface uses the [`interface*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createinterface.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._interface%2A%29%29) form to inherit from the [`prop:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._prop~3acustom-write%29%29) struct-type property. However, this is not true for all generic interfaces, just the ones that correspond to struct-type-properties.

P.S. Don't worry too much about the documentation saying [`prop:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._prop~3acustom-write%29%29) is deprecated. It's just not necessary for "users" to use it, since [`gen:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._gen~3acustom-write%29%29) exists for structs and [`printable<%>`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objectprinting.html) exists for classes. It's deprecated as an interface, but as an implementation it is not going away. In that way it's "safe" to use without worrying.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Knauth! How much should I read into the documentation indicating that `prop:custom-write` is deprecated?

Comment: It depends what deprecated means. It's not necessary for "users" to use it, since `gen:custom-write` exists for structs and `printable<%>` exists for classes. However, it will never "go away", Racket is not planning to remove it or replace it. In that way it's "safe" to use without worrying.

Comment: I'm curious: Is this only for `custom-write` or are there other generic interfaces or struct-type properties that you might want on the objects of a class?

Comment: for now I'm interested in only `custom-write`