# How to print custom objects?

Tags: racket, custom-object

This references says printable<%> should be implemented, and that it seems to be a wrapper around prop:custom-write.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objectprinting.html

But the docs for prop:custom-write say it's deprecated in favor of gen:custom-write.

Comment: See: [_gen:custom-write for Racket classes_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844089/gencustom-write-for-racket-classes). Don't worry too much about prop:custom-write being deprecated: it's just not necessary for "users" to use because `gen:custom-write` and `printable<%>` both exist as a replacement interface

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Racket class and object system, then implement `printable<%>`.
If you are using structs, then use `gen:custom-write`.